# Force click to edit text in a list in macOS with swiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

What is the best way to use Force Click to edit some text in a list like this in swiftui?[image: renaming text]

I have tried to use a ZStack and some variables to show the textfield but it doesn't look as good. is there some easier way to do this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?